# Нужно чтобы числа рандомились с 97 до 122

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, функции

Вылетает с ошибкой "прекращена работа программы":

```
srand(time(0));
int a = rand() % 123 + 97;
```

Comment: Вылетает **в каком месте**? Здесь никакой крамолы нет. А вот что у вас рядом в исходнике? мы же не телепаты... Да, только учтите, что у вас случайное число - от 97 до 219. Чтоб от 97 до 122 включительно - нужно `rand()%26+97`.

Comment: @Harry проблему решил, спасибо.

Comment: C [rand()  не рекомендуется в c++](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Можно [`<random>` API использовать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19728404/4279)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::default_random_engine u{};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{};

u.seed(std::random_device()()); // Аналог srand

d(u,uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type{97,122});
```

Держи, этот по-лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Подключи библиотеки:

- `<cstdlib>` - для `srand()` и `rand()`
- `<ctime>` - для `time()`